# Numpy: Loop alternative, Optimization

Tags: python, numpy

Since I am new to Numpy , I am facing problems implementing a particular code that I wrote in C++

```
for(i=0;i<h;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<w;j++)
    {
        val=0;
        for(i1=-size;i1<=size;i1++)
        {
            for(j1=-size;j1<=size;j1++)
            {
                h1=i+i1,w1=j+j1;
                if (w1<=0) w1=w1+w;
                if (h1<=0) h1=h1+h;
                if (w1>=w) w1=w1-w;
                if (h1>=h) h1=h1-h;
                val=val+sqrt(pow(data[i][j][0]-data[h1][w1][0],2)
                            +pow(data[i][j][1]-data[h1][w1][1],2)
                            +pow(data[i][j][2]-data[h1][w1][2],2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am basically adding euclidean distance for [i,j] element with every element  that is part of the submatrix [i-size to i+size][j-size to j+size]

how do I write the code in python without having to use loops to perform some operation for each element in the numpy array that is dependent on its row and column positions. Or there must be some way of optimizing it.

This is my current implementation which is like VERY VERY SLOW

```
for i in range(0,h):
    for j in range(0,w):
        for i1 in range(-window_size, window_size+1):
            for j1 in range(-window_size, window_size+1):
                h1=i+i1
                w1=j+j1
                if w1 <= 0:
                    w1+=w
                if  h1 <= 0:
                    h1+=h
                if w1 >= w:
                    w1-=w
                if h1 >= h:
                    h1-=h
                val[i][j] += np.sqrt(((source_pyr_down_3_Luv[i][j][0] - source_pyr_down_3_Luv[h1][w1][0])**2)
                                    +((source_pyr_down_3_Luv[i][j][1] - source_pyr_down_3_Luv[h1][w1][1])**2)
                                    +((source_pyr_down_3_Luv[i][j][2] - source_pyr_down_3_Luv[h1][w1][2])**2))
```

It almost took 6 minutes to run this code.

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself? What problems did you have? What does the code look like and what error messages do you get? Why do you want to avoid loops?

Comment: have added my implementation in the code and also added the explanation to ur question so that the original question is more detailed.

Comment: If you have the C++ code you can just use Cython. In any case, `pow(x, 2)` is very inefficient whether in C or Python. Just use `x * x`

Comment: I was able to optimize the code by using spatial.distance.cdist from Scipy which is what I was doing. this reduced the time drastically from 4 minutes to about 10 seconds :P I further tried to reduce it using cython but scipy calls doesn't change whether u use cython or python so the implementation remains to about 6 seconds still after using scipy and cython both. :(

Comment: This and related questions demonstrate a common problem with python/numpy, when you have tight inner loops that has no equivalent numpy vector operations then you are essentially stuck no matter how hard you try to optimize. In these types of cases one should seriously consider other alternative such as C-extensions or better yet Cython.

Answer (score 3):

to access a subarray im numpy try:

```
data[i-size:i+size,j-size:j+size]
```

to edit this subarray (in this case simple +1 to  each element):

```
data[i-size:i+size,j-size:j+size] += 1
```

or to get another array containing the distance between elements of 2 arrays (of shape (n,2)):

```
data3 = np.sqrt(np.power(data1[:,0]-data2[:,0],2)+ np.power(data1[:,1]-data2[:,1],2))
```

I know that this is not a full answer, but I hope it helps you get started.

Comment: 'data[i-size:i+size,j-size:j+size]' will still require loops I guess. Python loops make the code very very slow as compared to c++ implementation, and if this could be done using Numpy then the code will become very fast. That is why I am keen on removing the loops

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the explicit inner loops and compute the matrix of euclidean distances directly by pre-extending the original matrix so that no checks are needed on element indices:

```
# Extend the matrix to avoid modular access
h, w, _ = data.shape
exdata = numpy.zeros((h+2*size, w+2*size, 2), data.dtype)
exdata[size:-size, size:-size, :] = data[:,:,:]  # Fill central part
exdata[:size,:,:] = exdata[-size*2:-size,:,:]    # Copy last rows to begin
exdata[-size:,:,:] = exdata[size:size*2,:,:]     # Copy first rows to end
exdata[:,:size,:] = exdata[:,-size*2:-size,:]    # Copy last cols to begin
exdata[:,-size:,:] = exdata[:,size:size*2,:]     # Copy first cols to end

# Do the actual computation
val = 0
for i in xrange(h):
    for j in xrange(w):
        dx = numpy.copy(exdata[i:i+size*2+1, j:j+size*2+1, 0])  # all x values
        dy = numpy.copy(exdata[i:i+size*2+1, j:j+size*2+1, 1])  # all y values
        dx -= dx[size, size] # subtract central x
        dy -= dy[size, size] # subtract central y
        dx *= dx # square dx
        dy *= dy # square dy
        dx += dy # sum of squares
        val += numpy.sum(dx ** 0.5)
```